# Adding toolbar type to an external list in a webpart yields double toolbar. 2 of them?

Tags: web-part

[image]Adding toolbar type to an external list in a webpart yields double toolbar. 2 of them?
I have an external list that I bought into a web part.
I wanted the toolbar to show but I'm getting 2 one on top of the other.

Really would appreciate your assistance.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use the business data list web part or check for other errors that may be related.

If you use the business data list web part, you should only see one toolbar. See the example at [Display business data on a SharePoint site](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/display-business-data-on-a-sharepoint-site-HA010216428.aspx). It shows the toolbar with the Actions drop down in the section *Display a summary of business data in a list.*

If you'd like to add actions to the list, see [How to: Add a Custom Action to an External List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558387%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and [Creating a Custom BCS Action in SharePoint 2010](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqRCORJ88uM).

Comment: Hello Tom and thank you.
However, under Actions, it displays " NO actions" and in the web part under view s I only see Read List although when I use the external list web part, I get full CRUD. Thank you.

Comment: Yes. I'm afraid that's what you get with an external list. If you'd like, you can add custom actions.

Comment: Would you please be so kind to point me over to learn how to add "custom actions" please?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqRCORJ88uM

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558387(v=office.14).aspx How to: Add a Custom Action to an External List

Comment: Tom Thank you!!!!!! :) Is there a way to give you props here??

Comment: Glad it helped. You can thank me by marking the answer correct and voting it up. That will help other sharepoint.stackexchange.com users when they have a similar question.